# css: why texts will move up after remove position:absolute

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h2 { position:absolute;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>This is a heading with an absolute position</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Question:

If I remove this line: `position:absolute;`, the texts in `<h2>...</h2>` will move up, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the default view, without CSS...**

When the `position: absolute;` is there, the margins are not collapsed.

[image]

---

When you remove the `position: absolute;`, the margins collapse, and it gets mingled with the body's margin.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add to css :

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? While this does not answer the question persay, this answer tells the reason why it happens (margins not collapsed). Thus setting the body margin to 0 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `position:absolute`,

the element is removed from the document and placed exactly where you tell it to go.

This tells the browser that whatever is going to be positioned should be removed from the normal flow of the document and will be placed in an exact location on the page.

It is also taken out of the normal flow of the document - it won't affect how the elements before it or after it in the HTML are positioned on the Web page.

[position:absolute;](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm)

Answer (score 0):

that's because of the default browser margin's, if you're setting the margin to zero, you can remove the absolute setting:

```
 h2
 {
 position:absolute;
 margin:0;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MGm36/

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because of the layout settings.

If you use `position: absolute` to `h2` then the parent element which is `body` tag will not resize its height automatically. thus, the body's default margin and padding properties will come up of the `h2` element. and when you remove `position: absolute` from `h2`, the `body` will increase its height accordingly to its child element.

This also happens with `float` property.

For understanding clearly yourself, give different `background-color`/`border` css property to each element i.e `body`, `html` and `h2` and check using your favourite developer tool.